# awk -v, print only a word of the whole variable

Tags: variables, awk

i've got a bunch of variables under `container[x]`, where x is an undefined number, and every variable consist of a word and numbers in this format `elegant_kalam: 5.30%`.

What i need to do is **take only the first percentage number of every variable (in this case, "5")**.
i've been lately learning awk, and with "-v and var=" found out i can take a variable instead of a file, the question is, **how do i take that number of every variable with awk, using a variable instead of a file**

what i came with is

```
MEDIDOR_ACTUAL=$(awk -v var="${container[$x]}" 'BEGIN {print var}')
echo $MEDIDOR_ACTUAL
```

but obviously im printing the whole line instead of what i want.

Comment: I think there was no reason to delete question. But anyway, hope it will work now.

Comment: @Marcin it still doesnt work, now i got a different error, but the question itself was misleading so that's why i deleted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass the variable to `awk`. Just use:

```
awk '{print int($2+0)}' <<< "${container[$x]}"
```

```
5
```

- `+0` will convert `$2` i.e. `5.30%` to a number `5.3`
- `int` function will convert it to an integer i.e. `5`.